# vue js input form binding from v-for loop data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am sending a post request from vue, the vue form is created with v-for loop as it is an array of data objects. Within the data objects there is another set of objects with a field. How do i setup the data structure? And how do i pass the data with id into vue data structure since the for loop creates more than 1 object? Appreciate any help here! thank you!

```
<div v-for="(list, index) in lists.items" :key="list.id">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ list.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    Select quantity of item: <br>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity of item">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div v-for="addon in list.addons">
                        Include addons: <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" :value="addon.id">
                        <label>{{ addon.name }}</label>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity of addon">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buy" @click.prevent="buy(index)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to send

```
[
    { item_id: id },
    { quantity: quantity },
    [
        [
            { addon_id: id },
            { addon_quantity: quantity }
        ],
        [
            { addon_id: id },
            { addon_quantity: quantity }
        ]
    ]
]
```

to back end. the addon array can contain a single object or multiple objects depending on whether they have been selected.

Comment: Are you editing the addon info already? Could you edit your post, showing us the data that you send to your backend? And show the function that you use to send.

Comment: i am not edditing the addon info, it is a checkbox for customers to select if they want addons. I have not sent anything to backend yet, that is the axios part which i am okay with. the problem i have is to construct the data structure to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by putting the entire array as an object into the buy function. Other arrays in the same loop will not be affected when I click on the submit for each array.

```
@click.prevent="buy(list)"
```

as for the input numbers into the list object, I declared as:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Quantity of item" v-model="list.main_quantity">
```

and the addon loop

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <div v-for="addon in list.addons">
        Include addons: <br>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="addon.id" v-model="addon.addon_id">
        <label>{{ addon.name }}</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity of addon" v-model="addon.quantity">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `list` structure is something like that:

```
list: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Foo Baah',
    addons: [
        {
            id: 100,
            name: 'Delta'
        },
        {
            id: 101,
            name: 'Bravo'
        },
        {
            id: 102,
            name: 'charlie'
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can handle this data on this way:

```
function(lists) {
    let tempList = []
    lists.forEach((item) => {
        let tempItem = []

        Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
            if (key == 'addons') {
                let tempAddon = []
                item.addons.forEach((addonItem) => {
                    let tempAddonItem = []

                    Object.keys(addonItem).forEach((addonItemKey) => {
                        let tempObject = {}
                        tempObject[addonItemKey] = addonItem[addonItemKey]
                        tempAddonItem.push(tempObject)
                    })
                    tempAddon.push(tempAddonItem)
                })
                tempItem.push(tempAddon)
            } else {
                let tempObject = {}
                tempObject[key] = item[key]
                tempItem.push(tempObject)
            }
        })

        tempList.push(tempItem)
    })

    return tempList
}
```

Comment: Hi Raphael, thank you for your time trying to help me. how will you pass the input number parameter of the main quantity & addon quantity? i am not aware of any method to do so. I have the index together with the list in the v-for loop to differentiate the different arrays when the submit button is pressed.

Comment: I didn't realize the problem that you had. I thought that you need to handle your data to send to your API. I hope my answer helped you.